# Nilsson Diagram

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics

The Nilsson diagram is one of the most complicated diagrams I have ever come across in Nuclear physics and there are just some things I would really want to understand

If we look at the slope of the 1/2[303] and 7/2[303] Nilsson orbitals, why are their slopes pointing upwards and downwards?

Also, does this trend depend on the signs of the quadruple deformation?

I am really lost and curious to find out why this is the case

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/648287/2451

Comment: This is not a homework-like question, this is purely based on me wanting to understand the diagram better @Qmechanic

Comment: @Qmechanic I am perplexed as to why you linked a closed question with no answer. Why? There are not even any links to an answer in the comments or any comments at all.

Comment: @joseph h: Phys.SE has only a handful of questions about Nilsson diagrams and that post is from yesterday.

Comment: Then why that post? I'm just curious.

Comment: @Qmechanic i feel like you wasting my time here. If you do not know the answer do not refer me to places which will add no benefit to my understand of this topic